# How do I locate instances of <CR><LF><LF> in a mysql longtext field

Tags: mysql

I would like to query my table for how many rows contain one or more instances of <CR><LF><LF>.  I can't figure out the correct syntax.  I would try

```
LIKE '%<CR><LF><LF>%',
```

but I don't know how to specify these special characters.  I did try

```
where mydata REGEXP '%[.CR.][.LF.][.LF.]%',
```

and that didn't get a syntax error but neither did it return any rows.   So, I realized I need a way to insert the test data as well!

Note: I am using mysql 5.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT ... WHERE longtextfield LIKE CONCAT('%', CHAR(13,10,10), '%');
```

13 = ASCII code for CR

10 = ASCII code for NL (which I think you mean by LF)

See the doc on MySQL's [`CHAR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_char) function.